# How does spring handle large groups of beans that need to be created

Tags: java, spring

Say you have a Card class and a Deck class.  Deck will receive 52 Cards. In spring, would each of these cards need their own bean?

Comment: What is your understanding of "own" bean? It's similar to Java - there is one Deck class, on Card class, but 52 instances of Card class. But value objects are not configured via spring typically... That's a beginner mistake, that everything has to be a Spring bean when using Spring...

Comment: You might have beans for the classes that are managing instances of these types, but not separate beans for each instance of a type in your system (e.g. you would not have 52 Spring beans defined for each Card instance). It might help to think about how classes are used to model your system before you start adding Spring into the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short**

All beans are objects initiated from a class. But not all objects initiated in spring is a bean.

**In Detail**

Bean is an object that is instantiated, assembled, and otherwise managed by a Spring IoC container. So unless otherwise you need 52 objects of Cards to be stored inside the Container for separate access as individual beans (obviously you don't need that), then you may create a bean for your Deck class and store your 52 card objects inside an array of it.

Here only one bean is created for Deck. Cards will be inside that bean.

I believe you are pretty new to Spring. Please read this documentation
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Comment: Your right when you say that I'm new to Spring. Combining your answer with Betlista's comment, it seems that the card objects would still need to be entered into the system individually if they would be entered through Spring.  There is no way to auto generate them like you can do using plain old Java.